# How to call browser function with URL/URI local to the client?

Tags: javascript, xml, url, firefox, opensearch

I want to call a browser function, e.g. [`AddSearchProvider(engineURL)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sidebar/Adding_search_engines_from_Web_pages#Installing_OpenSearch_plugins), which requires an URL to a XML-file. However, I want the user to generate the content of the XML-file himself, thus I want to call the function by passing (a reference to) the user generated content directly. It is key that all of this happens client-side only, such that no server is required to temporarily host files in the process.

I tried to encode the XML file into the URI:

```
uri = "data:application/xml;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent($('#edit-search-engine').val());
window.external.AddSearchProvider(uri);
```

But Firefox (57.0) rejects this approach with the following message:

[image: "Firefox could not install the search engine from: data:application/xml;..."]

<strike>I guess</strike>¹ Firefox expects a "true", remote, URL. How can I realize the above functionality without a server in the loop?

¹Update: Firefox is indeed enforcing the URL to be of HTTP, HTTPS or FTP:

```
  [...]
  // Make sure the URLs are HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP.
  let isWeb = ["https", "http", "ftp"];

  if (isWeb.indexOf(engineURL.scheme) < 0)
    throw "Unsupported search engine URL: " + engineURL;

  if (iconURL && isWeb.indexOf(iconURL.scheme) < 0)
    throw "Unsupported search icon URL: " + iconURL;
  [...]
```